Upload large file with POST requests fails due to MemoryError in Python
I am trying to upload a large file through an API to a remote server which requires the API_KEY in the request using POST method. I'm using Python 3.11.4 and my function works for small files, but fails for larger files (3GB). I can upload the file through the website, so the filesize is not the problem. Here is my function:
def upload_file(server, key_name, key_value, file):
    with open(file, 'rb') as f:
        return(requests.post(server, files={'file':f}, data={key_name: key_value}))

It works for small files, around 300MB. When trying to upload larger files I get the following error:
File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\filepost.py", line 92, in encode_multipart_formdata
    body.write(b"\r\n")
MemoryError

Any help would be appreciated.

The error "MemoryError" arises because the requests library attempts to read the entire file into memory when constructing the multipart form data for the POST request. This approach works well for small files, but for large files, it can overwhelm your system's memory resources.
What you may want to try is the file data to be sent in chunks to the server, significantly reducing memory usage.
import requests

def upload_file(server, key_name, key_value, file):
    with open(file, 'rb') as f:
        files = {'file': (f.name, f)}  # Use filename for clarity
        data = {key_name: key_value}
        response = requests.post(server, files=files, data=data, stream=True)

        if response.status_code == 200:
            print("File uploaded successfully!")
        else:
            print(f"Upload failed: {response.status_code} - {response.text}")

        # Optional: Track upload progress
        if response.iter_content(1024):
            for chunk in response.iter_content(1024):
                if chunk:  # filter out keep-alive new chunks
                    # Process the data chunk (e.g., update a progress bar)
                    pass


Thanks for your quick response. The only difference I noticed is the use of  stream=True but it still fails.
